# Remove Built in Windows 10 Start menu Apps

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Take a look at the image below, how can I remove the remainder of those items on the start menu, the seem to be permanent, though there has to be a way to remove them.

.
[image]

note: I already tried using ProcMon to review the events that occur when I open start menu,and launch the apps, and still could not locate the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Three of the apps you show (Connect, Settings, and Security) are part of Windows 10 Settings which is replacing Control Panel, so these are not removable.

It is generally recommended to leave Cortana and not uninstall it, but it can be done

https://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/

Comment: no I mean unpin, I dont want to uninstall/ completely remove them, so that itll just be blank without all that trash, all i use start menu for is to get out of my game when Im in fullscreen

Comment: You can Pin to Start (Start Icons) but that does nor remove them from the long Start menu.  So I do not think so.   Follow up: I just tested and Pinning to Start does not remove from the Long Start Menu

Comment: There must be a way to remove those pins via Registry or something

Comment: @PolisP2 What you want is not possible (specifically Settings).

Comment: Im just looking to unpin not uninstall/delete/modify them or at least make them hidden

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app-list not to show up in the Start menu:

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Start*
- Disable "Show app list in Start menu"
- No more app-list.

Comment: That works, but i want it to be completely clean from any pins, and that solution adds extra buttons on the left.

Comment: You can perhaps turn off left-side entries in *Settings > Personalization > Start > Choose which folders appear on Start*.

Comment: im sorry for all this, i found a 100% working solution https://superuser.com/questions/1398951/remove-windows-security-icon-from-start-menu-on-windows-10-ltsc i will now delete this question

Comment: I wouldn't advise taking ownership of Windows folders.

Comment: @PolisP2 - Your question isn’t eligible to be deleted.